# Cannot log in to bash

Tags: linux, ssh, bash, scp

I was trying to install ncurses on a virtual Debian server on VMware and somehow was unsuccessful. After logging out of the console, I realized that I could not log in anymore. I cannot use tools such as scp, WinSCP or SSH client to get into the server. When I try to log in on the getty console, I get the below message and find myself at the login prompt again. In short, I'm locked out of the [virtual] server. This is a production server and therefore rebooting it would be a last resort.

I have downloaded a couple live CDs - Damn small Linux and Slitaz - which unfortunately cannot detect the VMs hard drives. Would changing the VM's hard drive controller lead to data loss?

```
login as: saichovsky
saichovsky@172.16.13.7's password:
Linux myhost 2.6.32-5-amd64 #1 SMP Wed Jan 11 14:00:43 UTC 2012 x86_64

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
Last login: Fri Nov  2 17:39:03 2012 from 192.168.3.166
-bash: error while loading shared libraries: libncurses.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Since you did not mention anything about the file system, I assume it is a regular file system. Therefore, you can't mount it on another VM while your production VM is running. How exactly did you try to see the hard drives with a live CD while the VM is running, without rebooting it from the CD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1 : ssh to sh shell**

Try following if you have ssh access to the host

`ssh username@hostname "/bin/sh -i"`

That will let you login with **sh** instead of bash if successful.

**Method 2 : mounting VM Disk with another VM**

I posted the step at https://superuser.com/questions/501861/locked-out-of-opensuse-after-editing-etc-pam-d-xdm/501927#501927. But he was able to resolve in another way. I will just paste the step here if you want to go this route

VM1: The trouble VM

VM2: Another working VM with root access.

1. Shutdown both VMs.
2. Make a copy of VM1 virtual disk file.
3. Addn VM1 virtual disk into VM2 disk controller as a second disk.
4. Start VM2.
5. Gain root access.
6. Mount VM1 disk.
   Let assume VM1 root partition is /dev/sdb1

```
    mkdir /mnt/sdb1
    mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/sdb1
```

7. Modify the file accordingly.
8. Shutdown VM2.
9. Remove VM1 disk from VM2.
10. Start VM1 and test.

Comment: Thanks John, I solved the problem yesterday. I used the second approach, using the lvm2 package. There was no data loss :-) I didn't know that I could specify the login shell that I wish to use on ssh. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use a Debian live CD to rescue the system. Many specialized live CDs such as those you mentioned have kernels with only a very limited set of drivers. Since it's a Debian system, the Debian installation media should have the necessary drivers.